# Spring REST how to response object with binary field

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger, multipart

how can i send response with Spring MVC this object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DeviceSummaryResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Конфигурация устройства", required = true)
    private ConfigResponse config;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "GPX файл с маршрутом устройства", required = true)
    private InputStream route;
}
```

i try this, but it dont work due to 'route' field, converter error.

```
@GetMapping(DEVICE_ID_PATH)
public ResponseEntity<DeviceSummaryResponse> getDeviceSummary(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {

    log.debug("REST request to get summary for complex with id = {}", id);

    var deviceSummary = mobileComplexService.getSummary(id);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(deviceSummaryMapper.toResponse(deviceSummary));
}
```

i need to do as described in the specification:

```yaml
DeviceSummaryResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
          properties:
           ...
          ...
        route:
          type: string
          format: binary
          description: GPX файл с маршрутом устройства
      required:
        - config
        - route
```

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) on your InputStream and use the byte-array constructor of String.

```java
InputStream route;
…
byte[] routeBytes = route.readAllBytes();
String routeBinary = new String(routeBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // for UTF-8 encoding
```

Comment: i dont understand how it can helps me?

Comment: Well, maybe you can provide more context like the exact error message and the lines of your `deviceSummaryMapper` where the error occurs.

I just provided code according your title how you would response with a binary object, when you have an `InputStream`.